# Keep only the latest files on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pdf, version-control, large-files

Is there a possible way to keep only the latest version of some specific files on GitHub?

For example, I want to upload some pdf files to GitHub, but I don’t want to waste too much space keeping the history of those pdfs.

Although upload binary files to GitHub is not a good idea, it is really convenient.

Comment: Are the pdfs changing often? If no, it won't take up additional space. If yes, why don't you want to keep their history?

Comment: The point of Git is to track history. If you have specific things you don't want history for, you could put them elsewhere in a place without history, and link to them from where they are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.  Git is designed to track the history of a project, and if you don't want to track history, then you should not use Git.  You can use a regular website, or a cloud bucket, if you'd like to store or persist data without storing history.

Note that Git LFS is not a good choice for this, because it also keeps history.  The only difference is that files that you aren't using aren't on your local machine; they're only kept on the server.  If you don't want to keep history, then there's no point in persisting old versions anywhere, even on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store large files without bloating the repository.

Or consider whether this is an appropriate use of Git; perhaps use cloud storage such as Amazon S3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store large files without bloating the repository.

You need to be careful storing large blobs inside of Git projects.  Github publishes some guidelines around this...